# Angular 5 HTTPClient/HTTPHeader 'Preflight response is not successful'

Tags: http, google-api, angular5, google-oauth

OK so I'm making a request to the Google Contacts API and I have on my backend a Node server that I authenticate and retrieve a Google API token from. When I try to send this token however I get a preflight error from the code below:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('GData-Version', '3.0')
          .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
          .append('Content-Type', ['application/atom+xml', 'charset=UTF-8', 'type=feed']);


http.get('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/'
          + _authService.getAuthUser().email + '/full', { headers: headers })
          .subscribe(contacts => {
            console.log(contacts);
          });
```

Here is a link to the API endpoint docs I'm trying to use:

[Contacts API docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts)

**Any idea on how to resolve this issue?**

Comment: This is a cors error.   What did you add as js origin in developers console?   Also try people API its easier not related to the issue just a comment

Comment: @Dalm it was a browser issue

Answer (score 2):

OK so the issue is with the browser. By default neither chrome nor safari would allow me to request a resource outside of my web app from localhost. Workarounds would be to install a plugin or turn off browser security like so: [Bypass CORS for local testing](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/08/bypass-cors-errors-testing-apis-locally/)

But in the end I just opted to make my requests from the API which is a node server also running locally but CORS enabled then have the result sent to my frontend application.